# python: can't open file 'C:\Program': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, localstack

I installed `localstack` using:

```
pip install localstack
```

Installation successfully completed.

```
localstack==0.12.19.1
localstack-client==1.26
localstack-ext==0.12.19.2
localstack-plugin-loader==1.0.0

Python 3.9.6
```

System environment path:

```
C:\Program Files\Python39\Scripts\
C:\Program Files\Python39\
```

Python location on PC:

[image]

When I use any command related to `localstack`, I'm getting the below error:

[image]

```
C:\Users\BRT.JNEHME\Desktop\FRC\freight_rate_collector-main>localstack -h

C:\Users\BRT.JNEHME\Desktop\FRC\freight_rate_collector-main>python C:\Program Files\Python39\Scripts\\localstack -h
python: can't open file 'C:\Program': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Anyone have any idea about this issue ?

Comment: The filename has spaces, so try enclosing it in quotes: ``python "C:\Program Files\Python39\Scripts\\localstack" -h``

Answer (score 2):

You need to add quote to your python command because you have spaces in your path

In other words, you should write this :

```sh
python "C:\Program Files\Python39\Scripts\localstack" -h
```

Instead of this

```sh
python C:\Program Files\Python39\Scripts\\localstack -h
```

The error comes from the command you enter: the syntax is not correct.

When you write a command and this command has a path where spaces can be found (here it is your case with Program Files), you must add quotes to the whole path so that the path is interpreted as a single argument and not two arguments (because on the command line, adding a space indicates the addition of a parameter)

Comment: but I'm writing only: localstack -h as mentioned in the official DOCS

Comment: Add more explanations

Comment: @Tarik, they do not have access to write that path, meaning it is a script.

Comment: Already upvoted you. Please, add the explanations in the answer.

Comment: command written: `localstack --version`
reply I got: 
`C:\Users\BRT.JNEHME\Desktop\FRC\freight_rate_collector-main>python C:\Program Files\Python39\Scripts\\localstack --version
python: can't open file 'C:\Program': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: The reason is the same, use 
python "C:\Program Files\Python39\Scripts\localstack" --version

Comment: I am not writing this: `python C:\Program Files\Python39\Scripts\\localstack --version` 
It's automatically appear when I send this comment `localstack --version`

Comment: I have the impression that the problem come from your terminal or your path.
Can you try the command in a "real" prompt ? Plus, can you try by making "cd "C:\Program Files\Python39\Scripts\" before ?

Comment: same error @avimimoun . if I use `python "C:\Program Files\Python39\Scripts\\localstack" --version` 
instead of `localstack --version` It will run successfully